# 0Auth2 Stuck on Permission Page

Tags: swift, xcode

Currently having an issue with 0auth2 permissions. It keeps on getting stuck to this page: [Stuck101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21lCH.png). It doesn't crash, just remains completely dormant.

The debug console shows this:

```
[Debug] OAuth2: Initialization finished
[Debug] OAuth2: Looking for items in keychain
[Debug] OAuth2: Starting authorization
[Debug] OAuth2: No access token, checking if a refresh token is available
[Debug] OAuth2: Error refreshing token: I don't have a refresh token, not 
trying to refresh
[Debug] OAuth2: Opening authorize URL embedded: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state=7A3CEE60&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+offline_access+User.Read+Mail.Read+Calendars.Read&redirect_uri=KTracker2%3A%2F%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&client_id=584bb6db-5b71-4d7c-9015-fab8a9dfae4c
2018-05-09 04:49:47.198828+0100 KTracker2[8281:180974] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
```

My App delegate file houses this code:

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  KTracker2
//
//  Created by CaudyMac  on 07/05/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Kallum Caudwell. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
 @UIApplicationMain
      class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        if url.scheme == "KTracker2" {
            let service = OutlookService.shared()
            service.handleOAuthCallback(url: url)
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Service Code is here:

```
//  OutlookService.swift
//  KTracker2
//  Created by CaudyMac  on 09/05/2018. 
//  Copyright © 2018 Kallum Caudwell. All rights reserved.


import Foundation
import p2_OAuth2
import SwiftyJSON

      class OutlookService {

        // Configure the OAuth2 framework for Azure
        private static let oauth2Settings = [
            "client_id" : "584bb6db-5b71-4d7c-9015-fab8a9dfae4c",
            "authorize_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
            "token_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
            "scope": "openid profile offline_access User.Read Mail.Read Calendars.Read",
            "redirect_uris": ["KTracker2://oauth2/callback"],
            "verbose": true,
            ] as OAuth2JSON

        private static var sharedService: OutlookService = {
            let service = OutlookService()
            return service
        }()

        private let oauth2: OAuth2CodeGrant

        private init() {
            oauth2 = OAuth2CodeGrant(settings: OutlookService.oauth2Settings)
            oauth2.authConfig.authorizeEmbedded = true
            //oauth2.authConfig.ui.useSafariView = false

            userEmail = ""
        }

        class func shared() -> OutlookService {
            return sharedService
        }

    var isLoggedIn: Bool {
        get {
            return oauth2.hasUnexpiredAccessToken() || oauth2.refreshToken != nil
        }
    }

    func handleOAuthCallback(url: URL) -> Void {
        oauth2.handleRedirectURL(url)
    }

    func login(from: AnyObject, callback: @escaping (String?) -> Void) -> Void {
        oauth2.authorizeEmbedded(from: from) {
            result, error in
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                callback(unwrappedError.description)
            } else {
                if let unwrappedResult = result, let token = unwrappedResult["access_token"] as? String {
                    // Print the access token to debug log
                    NSLog("Access token: \(token)")
                    callback(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func logout() -> Void {
        oauth2.forgetTokens()
    }

    func makeApiCall(api: String, params: [String: String]? = nil, callback: @escaping (JSON?) -> Void) -> Void {
        // Build the request URL
        var urlBuilder = URLComponents(string: "https://graph.microsoft.com")!
        urlBuilder.path = api

        if let unwrappedParams = params {
            // Add query parameters to URL
            urlBuilder.queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()
            for (paramName, paramValue) in unwrappedParams {
                urlBuilder.queryItems?.append(
                    URLQueryItem(name: paramName, value: paramValue))
            }
        }

        let apiUrl = urlBuilder.url!
        NSLog("Making request to \(apiUrl)")

        var req = oauth2.request(forURL: apiUrl)
        req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let loader = OAuth2DataLoader(oauth2: oauth2)

        // Uncomment this line to get verbose request/response info in
        // Xcode output window
        //loader.logger = OAuth2DebugLogger(.trace)

        loader.perform(request: req) {
            response in
            do {
                let dict = try response.responseJSON()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let result = JSON(dict)
                    callback(result)
                }
            }
            catch let error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let result = JSON(error)
                    callback(result)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var userEmail: String

    func getUserEmail(callback: @escaping (String?) -> Void) -> Void {
        // If we don't have the user's email, get it from
        // the API
        if (userEmail.isEmpty) {
            makeApiCall(api: "/v1.0/me") {
                result in
                if let unwrappedResult = result {
                    let email = unwrappedResult["mail"].stringValue
                    self.userEmail = email
                    callback(email)
                } else {
                    callback(nil)
                }
            }
        } else {
            callback(userEmail)
        }
    }

    func getInboxMessages(callback: @escaping (JSON?) -> Void) -> Void {
        let apiParams = [
            "$select": "subject,receivedDateTime,from",
            "$orderby": "receivedDateTime DESC",
            "$top": "10"
        ]

        makeApiCall(api: "/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages", params: apiParams) {
            result in
            callback(result)
        }
    }

    func getEvents(callback: @escaping (JSON?) -> Void) -> Void {
        let apiParams = [
            "$select": "subject,start,end",
            "$orderby": "start/dateTime ASC",
            "$top": "10"
        ]

        makeApiCall(api: "/v1.0/me/events", params: apiParams) {
            result in
            callback(result)
        }
    }

    func getContacts(callback: @escaping (JSON?) -> Void) -> Void {
        let apiParams = [
            "$select": "givenName,surname,emailAddresses",
            "$orderby": "givenName ASC",
            "$top": "10"
        ]

        makeApiCall(api: "/v1.0/me/contacts", params: apiParams) {
            result in
            callback(result)
        }
    }
}
```

I also have KTracker2 added in the plist files

Any ideas to why my app lies dormant would be great. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You did add the KTracker2 url scheme to the project (plist), right ?

Comment: Yup its added correctly